# Azure Time Sync Service without Internet Access

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure, ntp

Is there a feature for Azure similar to Amazon Time Sync Service which can be used with Azure VMs to have time synchronization without Internet access?

I could also find references to `0.amazon.pool.ntp.org`, does Azure has something similar?

Ref: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/set-time.html#configure_ntp

Comment: Note that using `0.amazon.pool.ntp.org` **does** require Internet access.  The AWS Stratum 3 NTP clock that does not require Internet access is accessible at `169.254.169.123`.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot, yes that's right.

Comment: @Ranjandas finally did you find any such service for Azure?  :D

Comment: @beginer The closest you could get based on Azure documentation is to depend on the `host` timing on which the VM is running using VMICTimeSync. [azure-doc](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/time-sync#host-only). Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

In fact, Azure VM needs Internet access, if you block all Internet access, you could not access this VM. Azure VM need access Azure data center. Port 80 and 443(outbound) need enable.

In a Azure VM, you could not modify the time, Azure will auto time sync the time.

More information about this please refer to this [blog](https://blog.codingoutloud.com/2011/08/25/azure-faq-how-frequently-is-the-clock-on-my-windows-azure-vm-synchronized/).

Comment: Any update about this?

Comment: Reference is woefully out of date, your advice is totally incorrect as of the answer date